# How to save to disk several 2D np.arrays each having the second dimension variable in size?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, data-science

I am getting some results in the form of np.arrays of size (`no_of_rows`, 2), where `no_of_rows` varies from array to array.

I want to save these results to disk for later usage (plotting). In any way, it doesn't matter how, but if possible in the most efficient way in terms of REOPENING/USING time-consumed-wise.

I can do anything with these 2D arrays. My thought was to create a `.npy` file containing a 3D tensor of shape (no_of_matrices, ? , 2), but that ? is my problem. Each 2D array can potentially have a different `no_of_rows`. So I abandoned this idea.

I now made a list of these 2D np.arrays. I now want to save that list to disk.
I have read about `np.savez`, but this doesn't preserve the order of saving. That is, when loading back in memory, I won't know which array is which, apart from many if's statements to check the `no_of_lines` of each array and match it to what it means for when plotting it later.

Do I have any chance to store these arrays in 1 SINGLE file, or do I just have to resort to creating multiple files, named in a distinctive way, one for each 2D array, and then access these files individually when plotting?

[PS: I can only have a maximum of 100-ish of such 2D arrays, usually having less than 10.]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npz with key arguments to identify each array and thus no longer have a problem of non preserving order.

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(5)*-1

f1={'my_key1':a}
f2={'my_key2':b}

np.savez_compressed('my_archive.npz', **f1, **f2)
```

Read your archive as follows:

```
>>>print(np.load('my_archive.npz')['my_key2'])
[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments, the solution presented above is not viable if we want to automatically register *N* np.arrays.
The solution is therefore to create a single dictionary with *N* entries:

```
f = {}
f['my_key1'] = a
f['my_key2'] = b

np.savez_compressed('my_archive.npz', **f)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have anything in mind for programatically defining the f's? I am now trying ```'f_%d' % i  = {names[i] : final_coords_at_detectorscreen_container[i]}``` inside a for-loop based on index ```i```, but it doesn't work: ```SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator```. I would like then to do: ```np.savez_compressed('my_archive.npz', **something_based_on_the_fs)``` Clearly your answer is not viable if I have more than 5 arrays in my list in the way presented in the post.

Comment: Ok, so I now have a list full of dictionaries like you emulate, ```l = [{}, {}, ...]``` . I am now trying to use the ```np.savez_compressed``` with ```np.savez_compressed('filename.npz', **l[i] for i in range(len(l)))```, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, managed to do save via putting everything inside 1 big dictionary with many key-value pairs, as I found that 1 dictionary with 1key-1value only (as you do with ```f1``` and ```f2```) is a little bit redundant. I just then unpacked the big dictionary inside the ```np.savez_compressed()``` command as ```np.savez_compressed('filename.npz', **big_dict)``` and then access ```np.load('filename.npz')[key]``` where ```key``` comes from the list of all keys saved in the big dict.

Comment: Using a single dictionary is the right solution.  The operator ** allows you to add each element with its associated key

Answer (score 0):

You can save these 2D arrays to CSV files.

Concatenating all the arrays into one is up to you: you can concatenate all the arrays into a single one and save only one file, or you can save all the arrays you receive.